# Matcher, find and replace placeholders with values

Tags: regex, replace

I have an input String which is something like a query with placeholders, like this

```
#input String queryText, test, test2
//queryText is something like " SELECT stuff FROM stufftable WHERE oid_2 = $$test$$ || oid_2 = $$test2$$
```

Now my task is to replace those placeholders with the content of the inputs, the input variables have the same name of the placeholders, so variable test should replace placeholder $$test$$ and variable test2 should replace placeholder $$test2$$

Here's what I've written down as a test

```
    final List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/)
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(queryText)
    log.debug(pattern)

    while (matcher.find()) {
        list.add(matcher.group(1));
        String text = matcher.group(1)
    log.debug(list)
    log.debug(text)
    }
```

And the output I have from the logs is the following:

```
\$\$(.*?)\$\$
[test]
test
[test, test2]
test2
```

So the placeholders are found correctly in groups, the part i miss is how to replace the values into them. I've tried .replaceFirst but it loops in the while, I've tried .replaceAll but it replaces all the placeholders at the first time so the others are not even found.

I hope it's clear, it's hard to explain. I'm here for any explanation.

Comment: Are you using Groovy or Java now?

Comment: I ask as I am interested if you checked [this demo from my comment to your previous question](https://ideone.com/tmdGut).

Comment: You should put the names of the variables into a map as Tim suggested. There is no way otherwise. But then you need to use `Matcher#appendReplacement` as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to put the variables names and their values to a `Map`, and then use `Matcher#appendReplacement` to find the variable data in the map by the variable name. The code below is a combination of what the previous answers are about:

```
// Input:
String queryText = " SELECT stuff FROM stufftable WHERE oid_2 = $$test$$ || oid_2 = $$test2$$"; 
String test = "1";
String test2 = "2";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("test", test);
map.put("test2", test2);

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\${2}(.*?)\\${2}").matcher(queryText);
while (m.find()) {
    if (!m.group(1).isEmpty()) {
        m.appendReplacement(result, map.get(m.group(1)));
    }
    else {
       m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(0));
    }
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
// => SELECT stuff FROM stufftable WHERE oid_2 = 1 || oid_2 = 2
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/ackpDV)

In Groovy, it is as simple as

```
String test = "1";
String test2 = "2";
Map map = ["test":test, "test2":test2];
String txt = 'WHERE oid_2 = $$test$$ || oid_2 = $$test2$$';
print txt.replaceAll(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/) { k -> map[k[1]] ?: k[0] }
```

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/tmdGut)

Comment: Ok the groovy now works fine!! I'm sorry if I'm bothering you. 

One last question, is there any way to create this map automatically from inputs? I have this script with like 100 inputs and I was wondering if there was a way. Inputs and Placeholders have the same names.

Comment: The point is you need to be able to map the name of the variable to its value. Since you know the variable names beforehand, and you can manipulate the code, there is nothing that can stop you from creating the map "manually" (if you have a properly formatted list, just use Excel or soemthing to write the code quicker).

Comment: Okay, understood this. And what if I have one or more placeholders that aren't mapped.. like let's say I have $$test3$$ and $$test4$$ in my String txt, can I maybe throw an exception or assign a default value to them?

Comment: In both the solutions above you see an `if` condition where I check if the variable name is present in the map. If it is not, the whole match value is returned. You may change this. Say, in Java, replace `m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(0));` with `m.appendReplacement(result, "MY_DEFAULT_VALUE");`. In Groovy, use `{ k -> map[k[1]] ?: "MY_DEFAULT_VALUE" }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String queryText = "SELECT stuff FROM stufftable WHERE oid_2 = $$test$$ || oid_2 = $$test2$$";
    String regex="\\$+(.*?)\\$+";
    Matcher m=Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(queryText);
    StringBuffer sql=new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
       m.appendReplacement(sql, "$1");
    }
    m.appendTail(sql);
    System.out.println(sql);
```

you can try this .